# How to resize UITableViewCell after setting its size in HeightForRowAt func in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want the latest TableViewCell, to be as big as the TableView, but I want the old cells to return to normal size, everytime I create a new one.

I've already tried, doing it in the HeightForRowAt function, but every cell remains on the TableView size.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    var cellHeight: CGFloat = CGFloat()
    for cell in tableView.visibleCells {
        cellHeight = cell.bounds.height
    }

    let TableHeight = tableView.frame.height


    if indexPath.row == arr.count - 1 {
        return TableHeight
    }else{

        return cellHeight
    }

}
```

Is there any way to resize the cell after its creation, or any other solution to my problem?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just try to put constant number in a normal cell height

```
 if indexPath.row == arr.count - 1 {
    return TableHeight
 }else{
    return 40 // or whatever you want
 }
```

if you ask your self why?
First time your cells height will be **zero** and the last one will be **TableHeight**

Then each time heightForRowAt method called, your cells heights will be  = **TableHeight** and last one height also will be **TableHeight**.

because your for loop will return the last cell height from **visibleCells** and you have one visible cell `"other cells not visibles height = zero"`, so it will be **TableHeight**

Comment: Thanks, that worked. But I have dynamic cell heights, with AutoLayout, so if the cell is larger than the normal cell height, it will be cut off.